# Speeding up in R

Tags: r, accuracy, efficiency

for(i in 1 : n){
  y[i] <- length(X[X >= X[i]])
}

This is my code in R (partially given) to obtain the number of X's greater than or equal to each Xi, where X is a vector of values. When I run this code a million times (that is n = 1 million) it took around 5 hours to generate results.
Please let me know if there's any faster method of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered the ifelse command.  Also, if you know C++, R has an interface rcpp which you could read about in http://rcpp.org/.

Comment: If there are no ties and X could be sorted, you would have a very fast solution.

Comment: @DaveHarris  Thank you for the rcpp link. My c++ knowledge is not so good and i'm less familiar to it with compared to R. So what I actually tried here is to see whether there's any faster method, (might be a package) for this in R before going to rcpp. Thank you so much once again for your immediate feedback

Comment: @DaveHarris There are ties. If not, actually it's easier to go from the formula,   n - i - 1 for yi    :)  This has ties. That's the issue. Thanks

Comment: Sort them, create an index if you need to restore the original order.  Create two matrices or vectors called lower and upper.  Find you lower and upper bounds for ties.  If you are X[3] and the tie runs from X[2] to X[88] then 1,000,000-88 is Y[3].  Again you may need to create an index to map it backwards to the original structure.  You also may not need to know lower depending on how you structure your cases.

Comment: have you considered using the `rank()` function?

Comment: Although you've had positive responses, which should be useful, please read advice in the Help Center about software-specific questions. This one is arguably off-topic and likely to be closed soon, but you have asked other such off-topic questions and all this has been explained. Please respect the explicit limits of this site.

Comment: @Xi'an    I have not used that before. Let me try. Thanks

Comment: @NickCox  My apologies for this question if it's off topic. I'll try my best to avoid them in the future. This is not done purposely with disrespect. I do know the value of this site as I have used this so many times in so many situations. I hope I'd get used to the types of questions which are valid when keeping on touch with this site. I'm sorry for any mistake done by my side.

Comment: Please study https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic before you post any more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have ties, I assume you have a discrete distribution and therefore I simulate values with `sample`. My idea is to use an empirical cumulative distribution function. It's only a bit tricky because of the ties. Without ties it would be quite simple.

```
n <- 2e4
set.seed(42)
X <- sample(1:5, n, TRUE)
y <- numeric(n)
system.time({
  for(i in 1 : n){ y[i] <- length(X[X >= X[i]]) }
})
#user  system elapsed 
#1.89    0.00    1.91


library(data.table)
system.time({
  mindiff <- min(diff(sort(unique(X))))
  DT <- data.table(X)
  DT[, X1 := X + (seq_len(.N) - 1) / .N * mindiff, by = X] #break ties
  z <- DT[, {
    d <-ecdf(X1)
    (1-d(X)) * length(X) + 1
  }]
})
#user  system elapsed 
#0.02    0.00    0.02


all.equal(y, z)
#[1] TRUE
```

Timings will differ depending on your data, e.g., on how many unique values you have.

Comment: thank you very much. This explanation/ code is very clear